# Neighbour's tree is growing into my yard

Tags: trees

My neighbour has a rather large cheery tree that is close to the property line. It has grown so big that the roots are causing the fence to shift and the roots are taking over a section of our yard. What can I do to prevent this tree from destroying our property? And whom is responsible for replacing that portion of the fence?

Comment: Have you spoken to the neighbour about it?  Seems like the tree has to go. do you have a home owners association?

Comment: No. He doesn't seem to care too much about his yard. I will mention it to him. I'll try calling the city again too. Last time I spoke with them, they told me to call my insurance company.

Comment: Unfortunately, you will have to talk to your neighbor and convince him that it is bad for both of you and the cherry tree must go.  Better yet, if you can convince him that the damage is due to his cherry tree, he needs to pay for it.